# PHP "id3_set_tag" NOT responded

Tags: php, tags, set, id3

I recently used id3_set_tag and I didn't get any response (True or False)!
For testing, I used the sample code, but nothing happened. my server PHP version is : 5.6.

I used this sample code:

```
<?php
// test my php
echo "test1";
$data = array(
              "title" => "Re:Start",
              "artist" => "Re:\Legion",
              "comment" => "A nice track"
             );
$result = id3_set_tag( "myfilepath.mp3", $data, ID3_V1_0 );
if ($result) {
    echo "Tag successfully updated\n";
} else {

echo "failed"; 
}
echo "test2";
?>
```

only test1 printed and nothing else happened!

Comment: This indicates that PHP has encountered an error; see the "white screen of death" section of the linked reference question.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks, I got this error, Fatal error: Call to undefined function id3_set_tag() 
.
I searched a lot but can't find the answer on how to install PHP PECL through Cpanel.(if I think right what to need!)

Comment: You need to talk to your hosting company; it's probably not something you can install yourself, because it's part of the server's configuration.